# TortoiseSVN overrides command line svn proxy configuration?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

It was quite surprising today when we were having problems with the proxy, and then we noticed that TortoiseSVN would override command line svn. Is that suppose to happen?

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseSVN internally uses svn client libraries to communicate with the server. Hence both are shared the configuration. [SVN proxy](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#proxy) FAQ describes this.

If you would like to alter the proxy for commandline client you can have a svn wrapper batch file which will include --config-option with proxy configurations information in it.

Answer (score 0):

For TortoiseSVN, see
http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-registry

In the section Configuration, it says: "You can specify a different
location for the Subversion configuration file using registry location
HKCU\Software\TortoiseSVN\ConfigDir. This will affect all TortoiseSVN
operations."

Alternatively, you can specify it as an option when starting
tortoisesvn.exe (/configdir:"path\to\config\dir"). See
http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/apc.html

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you mean, but as far as I know, Tortoise is totally independent from any command-line SVN client installed on the same machine, and manages its own settings.

Tortoise seems to have its own proxy settings. See  [this page](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/ch05s25.html) for an illustrated guide.